# How to know if browser has PDF viewer or not?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, internet-explorer, pdf

I am viewing PDF into iframe. It works fine. But some of the client don't able to see it in IE. They get it as download option.

How can I identify if browser has pdf viewer or not and prompt user that he hasn't pdf viewer?

Note: I am using asp.net mvc 5 (c#).

**I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640719/webbrowser-detect-if-there-is-a-pdf-reader-installed), but don't help me. The problem with me some of the client has Adobe PDF, so no issue for below answer. But those who have nitropdf or chrome pdf viewer, below answer don't help me. I want to idenitify all pdf viewer. otherwise if client has some kind of pdf viewer then also alert will be display that no pdf viewer is installed.** And that's wrong thing.

I applied this code by getting help from [عبد النور التومي's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24056048/3330969) and it worked for chrome and mozilla. [Here is the js I modified](http://pastie.org/9272642).

But **IE still not respond to it.** I don't know how to check in IE that it has pdf viewer or not. 
For IE, I'm getting following error though there is pdf viewer is there:

[image]

Comment: this solutions is to check if pdf reader is installed: [Webbrowser, detect if there is a PDF reader installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640719/webbrowser-detect-if-there-is-a-pdf-reader-installed)

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? (reopen vote)

Comment: @VDesign, It doesn't help me for all browser and all client

Comment: @bjb568, It doesn't help me for all browser and all client

Comment: @DKS Ok, which client? Edit in more detail to make your question different.

Comment: The only viable way is to install a specific program on the machine. And that means one program per OS if you need to support multiple OSes.

Comment: @SimonMourier dont knw wht u saying?

Comment: @Dhwani Why don't you create your own PDF viewer ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721529/pdf-viewer-in-mvc-to-show-the-pdf-contents-in-view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried following solution by taken help from [عبد النور التومي](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24056048/3330969), which helps for any pdf viewer in chrome and mozilla

```
    var getAcrobatInfo = function () {

        var getBrowserName = function () {
            return this.name = this.name || function () {
                var userAgent = navigator ? navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() : "other";

                if (userAgent.indexOf("chrome") > -1) { return "chrome"; }
                else if (userAgent.indexOf("safari") > -1) { return "safari"; }
                else if (userAgent.indexOf("msie") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("trident") > -1) { return "ie"; }
                else if (userAgent.indexOf("firefox") > -1) { return "firefox";}
                return userAgent;
            }();
        };

        var getActiveXObject = function (name) {
            try { return new ActiveXObject(name); } catch (e) { }
        };

        var getNavigatorPlugin = function (name) {
            try {
                for (key in navigator.plugins) {
                    var plugin = navigator.plugins[key];
                    if (plugin.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name) > -1) { return plugin; }
                }
            } catch (e) {

            }

        };

        var getPDFPlugin = function () {
            return this.plugin = this.plugin || function () {
                if (getBrowserName() == 'ie') {
                    return getActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF') || getActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl');
                }
                else {
                    return getNavigatorPlugin('adobe acrobat') || getNavigatorPlugin('pdf') || getNavigatorPlugin('foxit reader');  // works for all plugins which has word like 'adobe acrobat', 'pdf' and 'foxit reader'.
                }
            }();
        };

        var isAcrobatInstalled = function () {
            return !!getPDFPlugin();
        };

        var getAcrobatVersion = function () {
            try {
                var plugin = getPDFPlugin();

                if (getBrowserName() == 'ie') {
                    var versions = plugin.GetVersions().split(',');
                    var latest = versions[0].split('=');
                    return parseFloat(latest[1]);
                }

                if (plugin.version) return parseInt(plugin.version);
                return plugin.name

            }
            catch (e) {
                return null;
            }
        };

        return {
            browser: getBrowserName(),      // Return browser name
            acrobat: isAcrobatInstalled() ? true : false,   // return pdf viewer is enabled or not
            acrobatVersion: getAcrobatVersion()  // reurn acrobat version for browser


   };
}
```

And I got following error for IE, Though I have pdf viewer installed in my browser.:
[image]

Then I solved it by [this link](http://www.public.madeinengland.co.nz/automation-server-cant-create-object-internet-explorer/).

Then I add new condition for IE 11 `trident` and now it works fine. Also I added option to check for `foxit reader`. you can add another pdf reader name also in or condition.

Answer (score 10):

There is a JS solution :

```
var hasPdfViewer = getAcrobatInfo().acrobat ==="installed";
```

Known that API getAcrobatInfo is :

```
// http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com
// @author: Ben Kitzelman
// @license:  FreeBSD: (http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause) Do whatever you like with it
// @updated: 03-03-2013

var getAcrobatInfo = function() {

  var getBrowserName = function() {
    return this.name = this.name || function() {
      var userAgent = navigator ? navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() : "other";

      if(userAgent.indexOf("chrome") > -1)        return "chrome";
      else if(userAgent.indexOf("safari") > -1)   return "safari";
      else if(userAgent.indexOf("msie") > -1)     return "ie";
      else if(userAgent.indexOf("firefox") > -1)  return "firefox";
      return userAgent;
    }();
  };

  var getActiveXObject = function(name) {
    try { return new ActiveXObject(name); } catch(e) {}
  };

  var getNavigatorPlugin = function(name) {
    for(key in navigator.plugins) {
      var plugin = navigator.plugins[key];
      if(plugin.name == name) return plugin;
    }
  };

  var getPDFPlugin = function() {
    return this.plugin = this.plugin || function() {
      if(getBrowserName() == 'ie') {
        //
        // load the activeX control
        // AcroPDF.PDF is used by version 7 and later
        // PDF.PdfCtrl is used by version 6 and earlier
        return getActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF') || getActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl');
      }
      else {
        return getNavigatorPlugin('Adobe Acrobat') || getNavigatorPlugin('Chrome PDF Viewer') || getNavigatorPlugin('WebKit built-in PDF');
      }
    }();
  };

  var isAcrobatInstalled = function() {
    return !!getPDFPlugin();
  };
  var getAcrobatVersion = function() {
    try {
      var plugin = getPDFPlugin();

      if(getBrowserName() == 'ie') {
        var versions = plugin.GetVersions().split(',');
        var latest   = versions[0].split('=');
        return parseFloat(latest[1]);
      }
      if(plugin.version) return parseInt(plugin.version);
      return plugin.name
    }
    catch(e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  // The returned object
  return {
    browser:        getBrowserName(),
    acrobat:        isAcrobatInstalled() ? 'installed' : false,
    acrobatVersion: getAcrobatVersion()
  };
};
```

Comment: I tried above but it don't work all time. my client has pdf viewing capability in his browser but still it alerts that pdf viewer in not installed. I don't think this solution works for all kind of pdf viewer of all browser

Comment: The problem with me some of the client has Adobe PDF, so no issue for below answer. But those who have nitropdf or chrome pdf viewer, below answer don't help me. I want to idenitify all pdf viewer. otherwise if client has some kind of pdf viewer then also alert will be display that no pdf viewer is installed.

Comment: I tried for IE, Though I have pdf viewer it shows No PDF Viewer. So I, alert error message, and I got message: `Automation server can't create object`. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you can use a library like viewer.js to display your pdf in a container.

see http://viewerjs.org/

Answer (score 5):

I think it can be check from the navigator MimeType

```
function isSupportPDF() {
    var hasPDFViewer = false;
    try {
        var pdf =
            navigator.mimeTypes &&
            navigator.mimeTypes["application/pdf"]
                ? navigator.mimeTypes["application/pdf"].enabledPlugin
                : 0;
        if (pdf) hasPDFViewer = true;
    } catch (e) {
        if (navigator.mimeTypes["application/pdf"] != undefined)
            hasPDFViewer = true;
    }

    return hasPDFViewer;
}
```

Comment: Warning deprecated feature ! Simply use if (!navigator.pdfViewerEnabled) { ... } https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/pdfViewerEnabled

Comment: @sdespont it is not supported by Safari which does have a pdf viewer.

Comment: @extempl acc. to the spec, Safari has a PDF viewer :  https://caniuse.com/pdf-viewer

Comment: @sdespont yes, that's what I am talking about. `navigator.pdfViewerEnabled` is undefined in Safari

Comment: @extempl oh sorry. Here is my corss browser solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055738/how-to-know-if-browser-has-pdf-viewer-or-not/73632217#73632217

Answer (score 2):

Since Safari browser [still hasn't implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/pdfViewerEnabled) the property in 2022 `navigator.pdfViewerEnabled` property, a cross browser solution must also check [the deprecated mime types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mimeTypes) `navigator.mimeTypes` properties :

```
    function isBrowserHasPDFViewer() {

        // Modern borwsers
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/pdfViewerEnabled
        if (navigator.pdfViewerEnabled !== undefined) {
            return navigator.pdfViewerEnabled;
        }

        // Old browsers or not compatible with pdfViewerEnabled like Safari
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mimeTypes
        let hasPDFViewer = false;
        try {
            var hasPluginEnabled = navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes["application/pdf"]
                ? navigator.mimeTypes["application/pdf"].enabledPlugin
                : null
            ;

            if (hasPluginEnabled) {
                hasPDFViewer = true;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            hasPDFViewer = false;
        }

        return hasPDFViewer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PDF format is a licensed adobe format, from my understanding it's probably not always going to be reliable detection if you need to account for all non-licensed PDF readers also.

However, there is this resource: http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/PDFReader/

The basic idea is:

- Detect all plugins running in the browser
- Search for `"application/pdf"` in the browser's `navigator.mimeTypes` array
- If the `navigator.mimeTypes` array test fails, a second test is run in the background (i.e. nothing shown to the user on the frontend) which sends the browser a lightweight "empty" pdf file to see if it can be interpreted

Of course the idea of running a test pdf in the background might be a costly solution (i.e. mobile users on 3G etc.) but it's probably going to be a pretty reliable method, and the good part is you only have to test your user once when they reach your domain and then set a `cookie` or `localStorage` item with their pdf config saved so you don't have to keep testing their pdf capability.

Answer (score 1):

A newer method is to use [Navigator.pdfViewerEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/pdfViewerEnabled):

```js
const haveViewer = navigator.pdfViewerEnabled || false;
```

It is in April 2022 only [supported in 67%](https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.pdfViewerEnabled) of used browsers, but will eventually replace the [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mimeTypes) `navigator.mimeTypes` method.

[HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html#pdf-viewing-support)